# How to connect hive to mysql using kafka connectors(i.e. source and sink)?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, hive, apache-kafka-connect

I have to make Kafka source and sink connectors for connecting HIVE to MYSQL.

I am not able to find anything on above question. I have looked the confluent website also.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has a JDBC Driver, therefore, try using the JDBC Source and Sink connector, for both.

Alternatively, Spark can easily read and write to both locations; Kafka is not necessary.

Comment: I am using JDBC source and sink connector to connect Hive to mysql database but its not working. Any reason?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing what error you're getting, or what your configs look like. Edit your question with both

Comment: Like I said, I cannot answer why it doesn't work without actual logs. A config doesn't show why it may not be working (plus, you need a valid connection url and credentials, not empty values). Edit your question, rather than using comments, please